# How do I create a dynamic advertising channel for my company?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ads

I work for a Casino and we have promotional ads running on some of the TVs out on the floor. Currently its done by having a detected channel that displays the ads running off a computers web browser. I have a Flash file which contains multiple scenes of various ads that I render out to a .swf and play it on the channels site.

I want to know if anyone can think of a better way to do this. My current method isn't very dynamic and requires a lot of time from me just to update it. My current workflow consists of Opening a flash template > Swapping the image with a new > exporting it to a .MOV > Converting it to a .FLV > adding it to the Master ads file > Rendering the Master file > Replacing the .swf.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? I would like to be able to simply add or remove ads that are in a queue with flash or any other Adobe program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can put each "advert" in separate file, maybe you can just create XML with list of ads to load by flash, and load them one after another?
In this case for update you'll have to update paths in XML.